# Android viewpager is not match_parent in LARGE screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager in my view as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ci_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and it has 3 fragments which are populated later via the adapter, so testing it on my NORMAL screen (my smartphone) it fills the whole device's width below the action bar, but when I test it on my LARGE screen (samsung tablet) it becomes part of the action bar and takes around 30% of the action bar, so it's not below action bar any more, it's positioned at the left of the action bar. what can cause this? thanks in advance

**EDIT**: this is my 3 fragments: frag_ci_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/BACKGROUND" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/ci_info_big_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ci_info_prev"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/prev"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/ci_info_horizontal_sv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/SCROLL_VIEW_BACKGROUND" >

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/ci_info_small_image_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ci_info_next"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/next"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <mp1.com.widgets.FilledTextView
        android:id="@+id/ci_info_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/ci_info_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and frag_ci_hotel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/BACKGROUND" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ci_hotels_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and frag_ci_wonders.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/BACKGROUND" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ci_wonders_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and here's how I create the tabs:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.ci_info_details);
    setActionBarTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.TITLE_CI_DETAILS));
    int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
    _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ci_pager);
    _tabPagerAdapter = new Ci_CityDetailsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //async job fetching some info
    Ci_InfoJob cij = new Ci_InfoJob(this, id);
    cij.execute();
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        //I assume here's the problem ??? it's adding the tabs to actionbar...
        _actionbar.addTab(_actionbar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here are screen shots for both devices.

This is the mobile:

[image: Mobile Device]

This is the tablet:
[image: Tablet Device]

Comment: have you create layout for tablet ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana yea I've put the views in layout-large folder, and almost 95% of the views are fine just my viewpagers are like this,